# Is there a way to add pinyin/furigana to a class with css/javascript?

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, ruby-characters

I've been scouring the web for a while now, on how to add pinyin/furigana to Chinese and Japanese respectively. I'd really love to just add like a class like `class="furigana"` to the texts that require it. I'm making a language learning game that will need to be able to display this information. Can anyone shed any light on this matter? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot do this simply by adding a class, you'll have to provide the content as well. Especially furigana are not fixed, a kanji can potentially have many different readings based on context. If you're just asking for the right markup for ruby (not to be confused with the Ruby programming language), there's an answer for that though.

Comment: Oh, they're different? I kind of skipped over those cause I thought it was the programming language.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

pinyin/furigana can be added using the *ruby* HTML element which is part of a [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/) and is [supported on about 95% of web browsers](http://caniuse.com/ruby) as of July 2017.

Example:

```
<ruby>漢字<rt>かんじ</rt></ruby>
```

*Edited to change link to W3C recommendation instead of draft and change browser support*

Comment: Firefox does now support this. **also** make sure to use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your head, otherwise the browser might assume a different charset like mine did and give some really strange characters.

Comment: The W3C working draft link is outdated, newer information can be found here: https://w3c.github.io/i18n-drafts/articles/ruby/markup.en

Answer (score 6):

You can add it to a custom HTML tag with CSS which is what I did.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style>
fg:before {
 content: attr(t);
 display: block;
    font-size: 50%;
    text-align: start;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

fg {
 display: inline-block;
 text-indent: 0px;
 line-height: normal;
    -webkit-text-emphasis: none;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<fg t="わたし">私</fg>はケンです。<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It got my attention due to the custom tag. I wonder if you had any problems with it. I have read that valid custom tags should contain a hyphen character, like .e.g. `<custom-ruby>`.